# Restrict class from instantiation and encapsulate it in property in another class

Tags: c#, nuget-package, class-library

Im writing a .net Standard class library and I want to publish it as an internal package,so i have two classes in same project let say as below :

```
 public class classOne
{

     public void SomeMethod()
        {

        }
}




 public class classTwo
{

     private ClassOne _classOne;

     public classOne clsOne
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (_classOne== null)
                        _classOne= new ClassOne ();

                    return _classOne;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

As you seen above I want the developers to use class one as a property inside classTwo Also I want to prevent the instantiation of classOne. just the only way to call classOne methods is through classTwo "clsOne" property.

```
    //I want this code
classTwo clsTwo = new classTwo();
clsTwo.clsOne.someMethod();


//And Prevent to do this code
classOne clsOnew= new classOne();
clsOne.someMethod();
```

how do i implement that ?

Comment: Use an internal constructor and it won't be possible to instantiate outside its project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about ClassOne not being instantiated outside of your package, you could make the constructor of ClassOne `internal`.

If you only want ClassOne to be instantiated by ClassTwo, you could make a public interface, IClassOne and make ClassOne implement IClassOne and be a private nested class inside ClassTwo.

```
public interface IClassOne
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class ClassTwo
{
    private ClassOne _classOne;

    public IClassOne clsOne
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_classOne== null)
                    _classOne= new ClassOne ();

                return _classOne;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ClassOne : IClassOne
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you paramecium13. All of my need just prevent classOne from instantiate,I'll use internal constructor just :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want ClassOne to be static.

It should look something like this.

```
public static class classOne
 {

   public static void SomeMethod()
    {
     // Your logic
    }

  }
```

Then in the ClassTwo constructor or where ever you desire that function call,

```
public class classTwo
 {

   public classTwo()
    {
      classOne.SomeMethod();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is a nested class.

```
public class ClassTwo
{

    public class ClassOne
    {
        // methods
    }
    // property
}
```

But how would you prevent instantiation? Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    private class Token
    {
        public static readonly Token Instance = new Token();
        private Token(){}
    }
    public class ClassOne
    {
        public ClassOne(Token token){}
        // methods
    }
    // property
}
```

Because the token class is private within ClassTwo, only ClassTwo can use it to construct ClassOne.

Answer (score -1):

You could modify access to the constructor of `ClassOne` by making it private.

If I understand your question properly the only purpose of `ClassTwo` is to allow access to a single instance of `ClassOne` in which case you can use the standard Singleton C# pattern to achieve this in one class.

```
public sealed class ClassOne
{
    // Make the constructor private
    private ClassOne()
    {

    }

    private static ClassOne instance;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public static ClassOne Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // only get a new reference if one doesn't already exist
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new ClassOne();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

Since the constructor is private we cannot create instances of ClassOne outside of the class itself.

```
// Valid
var instance = ClassOne.Instance;

// Invalid
var instance2 = new ClassOne();

instance.SomeMethod();
```